# Adapter TRENDNET USB A — PS/2 doesn't work on notebook Asus

Tags: usb, adapter, ps2

I have an adapter for connecting PS/2 keyboard and mouse to USB port on a notebook -- TRENDNET USB A (m) — PS/2 (see image below).

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with my ASUS notebook (neither plugged in USB 2.0, nor USB 3.0). But it does work with my desktop computer, which is already has PS/2 sockets.

Can I fix the problem somehow, maybe installing a driver? (Which one then?)

Regards,

[image]

Comment: If the BIOS of the notebook does not respond to the keyboard connected through this adapter, then maybe you need to update the BIOS.

Comment: Obvious question but does it work on another system?

Comment: What happens when you plug this in? Do you see any new devices in the device manager?

Comment: @Journeyman Geek As I wrote in the question, yes, it does work: "it does work with my desktop computer, which is already has PS/2 sockets".

Comment: @billc.cn, I saw "a new device" icon in the tray, then I even could move the cursor a few pixels, but not like with an USB mouse. It stopped working in seconds.